# Метод, возвращающий перевернутый массив через рекурсию Java

Tags: java, массивы, рекурсия

Есть метод, который должен вернуть новый массив, содержащий элементы исходного массива в обратном порядке:

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] input, int n) {
     int[] output = new int[n];
     if (n == 0) {
         return output;
     } else {
         reverse(input, n - 1);
         output[n - 1] = input[input.length - n];
         return output;
    }
}
```

Метод работает неправильно, в результате получается массив, у которого все элементы, кроме последнего, равны нулю (последний элемент равен первому элементу исходного массива).

Подскажите, где может быть ошибка в методе?

Comment: вы никак не используете результат рекурсивного вызова, у вас на результат влияет только `output[n - 1] = input[input.length - n];` для начального `n`.

Comment: @zRrr, вы не могли бы объяснить, что именно происходит в блоке else? Мне казалось, что если поменять местами строки reverse() и output[], то сначала элементу нового массива будет присвоено значение из входного массива, затем произойдет повторный вызов рекурсии и вновь будет присваивание значения элементу нового массива. Но это, очевидно, не так работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код не работает, потому как `int n` не меняется и вы всегда меняете последний элемент массива.

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] arr, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        return arr;
    }
    int tmp = arr[--index];
    reverse(arr, index);
    arr[arr.length - index - 1] = tmp;
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, теперь понятно

Comment: @user249023 Не за что. Пожалуйста, закройте вопрос. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] input, int n) {
    int[] output = new int[n];
    if (n == 0) {
        return output;
    } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                output[i] = input[n-i-1];
            }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Но по заданию надо рекурсию использовать

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще раз (с рекурсией):

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] input, int n) {
    int[] output = new int[n];
    if (n == 0) {
        return output;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            reverse(input, n - 1);
            output[i] = input[n-i-1];
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```